# iOS app url request fails to get JSON return from php page

Tags: php, ios, json, url, request

I'm trying to visit the php page from my server, but no return. The code below should be fine, because when I change my site address (site1111111) to another one (site222222), the code works. The site2 uses JSON.aspx, which I don't know the code, but returns:

```
 {aaaa:false}
```

Edit and Add: Not sure if it matters, when I say site1111111, it's actually site222222/subfolder/. End edit.

My PHP code is simple test, just populate the same json string:

```
<html><body>
$arr = array ('aaaa'=>false);
echo json_encode($arr); 
</body></html>
```

The iOS app code is here:

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://site111111111111111111/welcome.php";
    //urlString = @"http://site222222222222/JSON.aspx?function=ffff&item=aaaa";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
    //<7b226973 64696769 74616c22 3a66616c 73657d> //print data from site2222222
    //<3c68746d 6c3e0d0a 3c626f64 793e0d0a 0d0a3c21 2d2d5765 6c636f6d 65203c62 723e0d0a 596f7572 20656d61 696c2061 64647265 73732069 733a200d 0a2d2d3e 0d0a0d0a 7b226973 64696769 74616c22 3a66616c 73657d0d 0a3c2f62 6f64793e 0d0a3c2f 68746d6c 3e0d0a> //data from site11111 

         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"error==%@==",[error localizedDescription]);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"no error for request"); //both site1111 and site2222 print this out
             NSError *errorInJsonParsing;
             NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&errorInJsonParsing];

             if(errorInJsonParsing)
             {
                 NSLog(@"error in json==%@==",[error localizedDescription]);
             }
             else
             {
                 if ([[json valueForKey:@"aaaa"] boolValue] ) {
                     NSLog(@"YES");
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"NO");
                 }
             }
         }
```

When running the code, I got null json, printed from if condition if(errorInJsonParsing).

I don't know if I miss anything that connects my php and ios request. Please help. TIA!

Comment: If you visit the URL in a browser, what do you see?

Comment: I see the expected json string when I visit my welcome.php page.

Comment: So what happens when you run that objective-C code?  Set a breakpoint and step through it line by line.  Is data getting populated from the internet?  Is there a network error?  Is json empty?  Is there an error?

Comment: When running the code, I got json as null, print from if condition if(errorInJsonParsing)

Comment: print the data. NSLog(@"%@", data);

Comment: @fluke, please refer to original post for additional info. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with options:0?   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&errorInJsonParsing];

Comment: just tried. same results: null json results for site11111. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

site1111 is not returning json, it's returning html.  if you decode those hex bytes you'll see this:

```
<html>
<body>

<!--Welcome <br>
Your email address is: 
-->

{"isdigital":false}
</body>
</html>
```

Fix the site so it returns json and you should be good to go.

Comment: Just don't print any html stuff.  If you continue to have problems, you should probably start a new question with a php tag, as this is really not iOS related any more.

Comment: Thanks. will try that. Accepted your answer.